# C# converting dates

Tags: c#, .net

I am using a javascrit API that returns respectively dates as

GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time) or GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time) in Firefox

eg. "Mon Nov 01 2010 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)"
and

UTC 2010 or UTC+0100 in IE

eg. "Mon Nov 1 00:00:00 UTC 2010"

There is any way to convert all the date-strings as date time?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have examples of the formats each browser returns?

Answer (score 3):

You could take a look into `DateTime.TryParse`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx